# Azure Windows VM set up auto-start/shutdown

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machines

I'm just getting stuck at adding permissions for the automation account required to perform the auto-shutdown/startup for this Windows VM.

So I'm at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management#prerequisites but I just can't find any of those permissions in the VM resource group permissions. For example, I can't find Application Developer at all which is a required permission.

Does anyone know how I could complete that step? I already have the automation account created as my VM uses ARM, but I'm just stuck at the permissions prerequisites step.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortuantely the documentation is a bit confusing, as it is talking about two different types of permissions, without making this clear.

The Applicaiton Developer Role is an Azure AD role, it is not an Azure RBAC role. You will need to grant this Azure AD role, using the Azure AD part of the portal, to the user deploying the solution.

The rest of the permissions it is talking about are RBAC permissions. By the looks of the documentation there is not an existing RBAC role that has all these permissions, aside from Controbutor/Owner, so you would need to create a custom role and assign these permissions.

Comment: The other thing it doesn't make clear is that this permission is needed on the user creating the automation account and not on the automation account itself. I did log a comment on it eventually, didn't look like I was being understood... Oh well...